# Devices wth Support for BLE Services 'Location and Speed' and 'Heartrate'

Tags: hardware, bluetooth-low-energy

I need a BLE test device that supports at least

- Location and Navigation (0x2A67) <sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup>
- Heart Rate (0x180D)

and optionally

- Health Thermometer (0x1809)

Can anyone recommend one?

Edit: I'm not looking 'the best' one - simply any devices that support these services as i'm writing an app to monitor these services and need a physical device to test against my coding (i've used the spec's but have nothing to test against). I've purchased a few through ebay that have the sensors but all have used proprietary means and don't use the BLE standards

---

1: [Bluetooth generic attributes](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics)

Comment: Hi Ian, blanked recommendations are not very popular on this site and without any information how you want to use this people will not be able to give you *good* recommendations. Please provide some more context for your request.

Comment: @helmar thanks for the headsup - added a background to the rationale of my question.